# In groovy, how to replace multiple occurrences on specific lines?

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a build.properties file like:

```
foo=bar/1.1 
start=/data/home/hudson/Project-1.1/workspace/1.1
fred=wilma/workspace/1.1
```

Only on the 2nd line, I want to replace all the 1.1 with 2.2, giving:

```
start=/data/home/hudson/Project-2.2/workspace/2.2
```

I have come up with a way to do this in groovy, but I have a feeling that I'm going about it wrong:

```
String result = ''
text.eachLine { line ->
  if (line =~ /(?m)start=/)
    result += line.replaceAll('1.1', '2.2') + '\n'
  else
    result += line + '\n'
}
```

Is there a snappy, groovier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your file in a variable `text` like so:

```
def text = '''\
foo=bar/1.1 
start=/data/home/hudson/Project-1.1/workspace/1.1
fred=wilma/workspace/1.1'''
```

Or by doing:

```
def text = new File( 'props.properties' ).text
```

Then, one method (and I am sure there are more ways to do this), is to do:

```
String result = text.readLines().collect {
  it ==~ /^start=.*$/ ? it.replaceAll( '1.1', '1.2' ) : it
}.join( '\n' )
```

`readLines` splits the text into a list of strings (one per line), then you `collect` into a new list either the original line, or the line with the replacement (if it begins with `start=`).  Then, join this list of strings back together with a `\n` char between them into a single string again.

Hope this makes sense, and is what you were after?

Comment: Thanks for that...much more concise than what I was doing.  I guess I was after was a solution that doesn't require me to do the iteration line by line.  I'm wondering if there is a way to build a regular expression for this.  Something along the lines of /(^start.*)(1.1(.*))*$/.  So I'm trying to say "look for lines that start with "start", and then "1.1 and some text"...which may repeat on that line, before we see the end of the line.  For such a line, replace it with group 1, and then as many of "2.2" and group n as needed.

Comment: @Davey I'm sure something like that is possible, but it depends whether you want three lines of code that you can read and understand in the future ... or one line of regualr expression which makes no sense and needs completely rewriting when you come to need to change it ;-)

Comment: Why don't you read it into a Properties object? Change the value behind the "start" key and save it again? Even with the fancy groovy code above, you still have to write it later again. So bottom line I find this a bit irritating :D

Answer (score 0):

f= new File('test1')
f.withReader{ f.write it.readLine().replaceAll('1.1','2.2')}

Comment: That will replace every 1.1 with 2.2...but I only want to replace 1.1's on lines beginning with the word "start".